# Javascript algorithm to walk through indices

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I have 6 elements identified by class: `.item-1`, `.item-2`, ..., `.item-6`.
If the user clicks on an item, the item shall be renamed to `.item-1` and all the others shall be renamed accordingly, in the same order. For example, if the user clicks on `.item-3`:

1 . 2 . 3 . 4 . 5 . 6
click -^

The result:
5 . 6 . 1 . 2 . 3 . 4

I wonder if there is a better algorithm than two loops (one for clicked-item (3) to end-of-series (6), and one for start-of-series (1) to clicked-item (3)).

Here's the code that I already have:

This is how the HTML is structured:
`<div class="showcase-container showcase-container-1"></div>`

```
$(".showcase-container").click(function()
{
    var numberOfItems = $(".showcase-container").length;
    var clickedItem = $(this).attr("class").match(/showcase-container-[1-9]*/);
    clickedItem = parseInt(clickedItem[0].replace("showcase-container-", ""));

    $(".showcase-container").removeClass("showcase-container-first");
    $(this).addClass("showcase-container-first");

    var currentItem = clickedItem;

    while(currentItem < numberOfItems)
    {
        $(".showcase-container").eq(currentItem-1)
            .removeClass("showcase-container-" + currentItem)
            .addClass("showcase-container-" + (parseInt(currentItem) + 1));

        currentItem++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you have already?

Comment: The second part `two loops (one for click to end, and one for start to click)` makes the question less legible. Start/end what? This is refers to the position, a process or task?

Comment: The better algorithm is (perhaps) to work out what you would be adding to each number (in this case 4) then use modulo arithmetic to achieve the required result in one loop. That's easier to do if the items are numbered from 0.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson the first loop would go from item 1 to item 2, adding 4. The second loop would go from item 3 to item 6, subtracting 5.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, I edited my answer so to clarify the second part as well as to add the sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pseudocode using integer modulo:

```
K = ItemClicked (zero-based)
N = Items.length
for i = 0 to N - 1
    Items[i].Name = "Item" + 1 + (N + i - K) % N
```

For your example K=2, N=6, and for the first entry
 `num = 1 + (6 + 0 - 2) modulo 6 = 1 + 4 = 5`

Comment: Thank you. I always admired people like you ☺